# reading a file in rails app deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app deployed in heroku.  In the app I have a simple txt file.  I have a ruby script that loops on all records in this file, makes a URL out of it and then does other stuff with it.

I can not do this locally and then transfer the data to my heroku app.

From heroku console is it possible to run a traditional simple ruby script that would loop over a simple txt file in my heroku app?

Answer (score 5):

yes you can read a text file, as long as it is pushed to Heroku with your code, the syntax is the same as reading files on your localhost

```
s = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/some_text_file.txt")
```

Heroku does not allow writing files

Comment: You can write files to tmp directory, but they are not gauranteed to persist.

Comment: they will live while you work with them.. Nothing to say what happens after that.

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated, so use ::Rails.root instead.